# Associative arrays in Jquery with Traversing Each Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an Element Like

```
<div class="control">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="checkbox" id="1"><span class="controlText">Check Box</span>
        <div style="display: inline;" class="delete"><sup>x</sup></div>
        <div style="display: inline;" class="properties chkbox">Properties</div>
     </div>
```

This element is in a form with id userForm
What I do is when the user clicks on a button it calls a function and searches all the div`s with class control and gets information about the element in that div.

```
 if($("#userForm").children().size() > 1){
        var controls = new Array();
        $('#userForm').find('div.control').each(function(index, Element)
            {
                if($(Element).find('input').attr('type') == "checkbox")
                {// If element is of type checkbox
                    var attributes = new Array();
                    attributes[type] = "checkbox";
                    attributes[name] = $(Element).find('.controlText').text().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("_")+"_"+$(Element).find('input').attr("id");
                    attributes[required] = $(Element).find('input').hasClass('required');
                    controls[index] = attributes;
                    $.each(attributes, function(key, value) {
                        // here i need to print the array. 
                        // I need a format of the arrays like
                        //  controls[0]
                        //            =>
                        //              [type] = checkbox
                        //              [name] = chk_name_1
                        //              [required] = ture
                        //          [1] 
                        //            => .....  
                        alert( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'" );

                    }); 
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using an Array where an Object is indicated for the *attributes* variable. Javascript doesn't have "associative arrays", it has objects that are unordered collections of name:value pairs. Array is an instance of Object and hence arrays created by the Array constructor are both Arrays and Objects with a special length property and some handy inhertied methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly right, but there are some problems. On the lines where you assign values to the elements of the `attributes` array, you need to put the name of the elements in quotes:

```
attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
```

Otherwise, it's looking for a variable called `type`, which doesn't exist.

Your `.each` loop will work fine, so you just need to print the values in whatever format you like. Note that `value` in the loop is an array, so to print the `type`, for example, you will need:

```
value["type"]
```

You are also looping through the wrong collection, so change `$.each(attributes, function(key, value) {` to `$.each(controls, function(key, value) {`

Comment: Even though i have changed the code to
      attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
The Funtion $.each(attributes, function(key, value) {
       alert( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'" );
      }); 

is still not working....